# Tengo un problema con "grid"

Tags: html, css, grid

Estoy horas y horas y no encuentro el problema.

Quiero agregar grid a una de mis páginas ya quiero quiero aprender a usarlo pero no se adapta el contenido (imágenes, texto, etc).

Ya puse las columnas y las filas pero igual así quedó todo mal hecho. Por ejemplo si **pongo 1fr 3fr 1fr** en columna quedaría la segunda columna el triple de grande que la primera y la última, sin embargo la última queda aún mas pequeña que la primera.

Cómo seria eso posible si puse el mismo numero de fracción. Eso es uno de los problemas, también ya puse en que fila quiero cada contenido y se pone en cualquier lugar.

```css
#ind-grid{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:"headeri headeri headeri"
                        "sectioni sectioni sectioni"
                        "articuloi articuloi articuloi"
                        "sectionii sectionii sectionii"
                        "asidei asidei asidei"
                        ;
}

#HeaderI{
    background-color: rgb(253, 218, 185);
    grid-area: headeri;
}
#SectionI{
    grid-area: sectioni;
}
#ArticuloI{
    grid-area: articuloi;
}
#SectionII{
    grid-area: sectionii;
}
#Aside{
    grid-area: asidei;
}
#SectionIII{
    grid-area: sectioniii;
}
Footer{
    grid-area: footeri;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= , initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Mininos</title>
</head>

<body id="ind-grid">
    <div id="HeaderI">
        <div class="background-header">
            <header>
                <h1>Mininos</h1>

                <h3>Cat cafe ヽ(=^･ω･^=) </h3>

                <!-- MENU -->

                <nav>
                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="./index.html">Inicio </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="./pages/postres.html">Postres </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="./pages/michis.html">Michis </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="./pages/nosotros.html">Nosotros </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="./pages/ustedes.html">Ustedes </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="./pages/contacto.html">Contacto </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>

        <main>
            
            
                <section id="SectionI">
                    <!-- gato imagen -->
                    <article class="presentacionCafecat-fotoLocal"> 
                        <div class="centrar-media-tabla">
                            <img src="./assets/imagenes/gatocafe.jpeg" width="500px" height="450px"
                                alt="Un gato con un café adelante de él">

                        </div>
                    </article>
                </section>        
            
            <article class="ArticuloI">
                <!-- parrafo -->
                <div class="parrafo">
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore
                        et
                        dolore
                        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                        aliquip
                        ex
                        ea
                        commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                        fugiat
                        nulla
                        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
                        mollit
                        anim
                        id
                        est
                        laborum."
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <section id="SectionII">
                <!-- imagen gatuno -->
                <img src="./assets/imagenes/cati.jpg" width="560" alt="gato naranja mirando un cafe">
            </section>
            <div>

                <aside id="Aside">
                    <!-- video gatuno -->
                    <div class="centrar-media-tabla">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ndbk0yhrGA"
                            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </aside>
                <section id="SectionIII">
                    <!-- imagen gatuno 2 -->
                    <img src="./assets/imagenes/cafe.jpg" width="460" height="315" alt="café con gatito de merengue">
                </section>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <div>

        <footer id="Footer">
            <!-- footer -->
            <p><b>¡¡Podes ayudarnos donando y de paso participas en un sorteo que hacemos a fin de año!!</b>
            </p>

            <p>Datos para donar:</p>

            <p>CVU: 0000050649384958322 </p>
            <p>Alias: Mininos.donaciones</p>

            <p>
                Para participar en el sorteo se debe donar un minimo de $50.
            </p>

        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Nunca toqué `grid` así que no sabría cual es problema. Pero sugiero que leas [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Quizá te ayude a entender mejor el tema hasta que alguien te responda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que te hiciste demasiado lio con los divs, si un contenedor tiene la propiedad `display: grid;` significa que los que van a estar en 1 o mas cuadros de la grilla van a ser los hijos inmediatos, no los nietos de ese contenedor.
Hice una pequeña versión simplificada y comentada usando las propiedades que te están dando problemas pero podes agregar imágenes y lo que quieras, para acomodar una imagen dentro de un article por ejemplo podes declarar ese article como grid, y todo su contenido podrás acomodarlo a tu manera, en este caso use solo texto:

```
<body>
  <div class="mainpage">
    <!-- main page es el contenedor principal y contiene un header, un footer y distintas secciones y articulos, estos elementos se acomodaran en la grilla -->
    <header>
      <h3>Inicio</h3>
      <h3>Menu</h3>
      <h3>Cuenta</h3>
      <h3>Salir</h3>
    </header>
    <section id="section1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat harum tempore, quidem debitis praesentium cum commodi quasi, a cumque blanditiis ipsum? Amet ipsa ducimus quae odit sit, ut asperiores et! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus commodi, voluptatibus reprehenderit voluptas consectetur quaerat sit explicabo sequi ab consequuntur ipsum quo saepe autem dolores alias totam, maxime officiis deserunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt expedita doloribus, incidunt inventore temporibus voluptatibus reiciendis quaerat debitis quis, adipisci error perferendis. Pariatur officia error quae dolore, ipsa facilis quam?</p>
    </section>
    <section id="section2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eum, iure, inventore impedit, commodi quo eligendi labore unde odio sint quos consectetur accusamus atque veniam earum. Quisquam cumque sunt enim minima. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo qui nam libero iusto dicta possimus in sequi blanditiis molestias voluptatum, nulla atque earum sed obcaecati ad nisi ullam necessitatibus iure. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In doloribus tenetur laboriosam architecto ex quod aspernatur deleniti voluptatum quis ducimus dolorem magni asperiores pariatur ad, sunt atque sequi itaque quae?/p>
    </section>
    <section id="section3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eum, iure, inventore impedit, commodi quo eligendi labore unde odio sint quos consectetur accusamus atque veniam earum. Quisquam cumque sunt enim minima. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo qui nam libero iusto dicta possimus in sequi blanditiis molestias voluptatum, nulla atque earum sed obcaecati ad nisi ullam necessitatibus iure. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In doloribus tenetur laboriosam architecto ex quod aspernatur deleniti voluptatum quis ducimus dolorem magni asperiores pariatur ad, sunt atque sequi itaque quae?/p>
    </section>
    <article id="article1">
      <span>Title 1</span>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor velit odit aliquam est rem incidunt iusto dignissimos unde. A minima nulla vel exercitationem ullam. Non pariatur ipsa autem dolorum quisquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos expedita ratione cum ullam doloribus eligendi, eum molestias aliquid consequuntur vitae earum optio, id atque cumque magnam! Cumque obcaecati eius maiores?
    </article>
    <article id="article2">
      <span>Title 2</span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos quaerat quidem fuga voluptas provident delectus iure similique minus, ad doloremque consectetur totam ipsa sunt fugiat? Labore laudantium quae laborum nulla. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis numquam obcaecati error corporis maiores alias! Blanditiis quis cum eligendi veritatis repudiandae quo nisi neque, similique sapiente nemo voluptatum non cumque.
    </article>
    <article id="article3">
      <span>Title 3</span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae aperiam cupiditate ratione culpa perspiciatis! Culpa illo sed dolore assumenda, impedit odit? Ex obcaecati vitae omnis? Cumque quae nam eveniet optio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ea quod, nam ipsam quo minima optio perferendis quos iure velit doloremque in quisquam est reprehenderit rem incidunt, voluptates blanditiis? Sed.
    </article>
    <footer>
      footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer 
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Css:

```
body{
    padding: 5px;   
}

*{
    padding: 10px;
}

.mainpage{
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: grid; /* contenedor principal como grid*/
    row-gap: 10px; /* distancia entre filas y columnas en la grilla */
    column-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: .3fr 1.2fr 1.2fr .3fr; /* tendra 4 filas con tamaños diferentes entre si */
    grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 3fr 1.2fr; /* y las 3 columnas con la del medio mas grande*/
    grid-template-areas: "myheader myheader myheader" /* myheader ocupa 3 columnas de la grilla y 1 fila*/
                         "mysection1 mysection2 mysection3" /* esto es solo para reservar el espacio en la grilla para cada seccion, lo mismo debajo*/
                         "myarticle1 myarticle2 myarticle3"
                         "myfooter myfooter myfooter"; /* el footer ocupa 3 columnas y 1 fila*/
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.336);
}

header{
    display: flex; /* flex solo para acomodar los h3 del header*/
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    max-height: 10vh;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-area: myheader; /* como este elemento ahora es myheader, grid ya sabe que debe ocupar 3 columnas lo mismo que con footer*/
}

span{
    font-style: italic;
    display: block;
}

section{
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 25vh;
}

article{
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 25vh;
}

footer{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: myfooter; /* aca tambien el contenedor grid sabe cuanto espacio de la grilla ocupa ese elemento */
    height: 10vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

si yo no coloco la propiedad grid-area a algún hijo del contenedor grid, entonces el elemento ocupara 1 solo cuadro y respetara el orden de declaración en el html. En este caso no use Aside pero tranquilamente podes hacerlo y que ocupe más de una fila en lugar de más de una columna. Espero haberme explicado bien y cualquier cosa pregunta.